# How to design replace regex to catch invalid url characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

I am using `replace` method to generate a regular expression to correct urls with whitespace, e.g.

`https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ererf3wery/sweet tooth packages-5cec39de28ea9000459a69a7/providerImage/2019-05-28 18.45.29.png`

my `replace` method looks like this

```
String(provider.coverImage).replace(/\ /g, "%20")
```

but this regular expression doesn't work for this url

`https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ererf3wery/Papa/'s%20Diner%20Fish%20City-5d836f717de0dd078f1338ad/providerImage/pdfc.jpg`

I need some help on how to catch the invalid character in the url

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a backslash inside of your regex.

```
'String with spaces'.replace(/ /g, '$20');
```

Also, it might be a good idea to replace all the whitespaces with a **%20**. Luckily, theres a special symbol group in regex for that – **\s**.

```
'String with spaces and tabs'.replace(/\s/g, '%20');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use decodeURI.

`decodeURI(https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ererf3wery/sweet tooth packages-5cec39de28ea9000459a69a7/providerImage/2019-05-28 18.45.29.png)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: has failed to work for the second url having /'s character